# nlme: different degrees of freedom between groups

Tags: r, mixed-models, nlme

I have a time series dataset I'm analyzing using a linear mixed effects model in the `nlme` package in `R`. I suspect there is a significant interaction between herbivory (`dmg`; light, moderate, severe, very severe) and `aspect` (linearized), which I would like to test with the following model:

```
t <- lme(log(rad+5) ~ dmg * aspect,
         random = ~ 1| plot/id,
         corr=corAR1(value=0, form=~year| plot/id),
         method="ML",
         data=ts.df, na.action=na.exclude)
```

In my dataset `ts.df` (subsample included below), `rad` is measured annually on the same tree (`id`) at the same `plot`. Hence, the grouping structure in random effects and the autocorrelation form. The study is imbalanced and not all herbivory categories contain the same number of plots and/or ids.

The summary of this model reads:

```
summary(t)
                          Value Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)            6.032107 0.2802577 134 21.523431  0.0000
dmgmoderate           -0.378854 0.3385741  23 -1.118970  0.2747
dmgsevere              0.022603 0.3337714  23  0.067719  0.9466
dmgvery severe        -0.567943 0.3537478  23 -1.605502  0.1220
aspect                 0.076621 0.4422410 134  0.173256  0.8627
dmgmoderate:aspect     0.003509 0.5047725  23  0.006951  0.9945
dmgsevere:aspect      -0.108859 0.4867569 134 -0.223642  0.8234
dmgvery severe:aspect  0.116697 0.4732669  23  0.246577  0.8074
```

My questions are

**1. Why does the degrees of freedom differ between the interaction groupings (e.g. moderate:aspect vs severe:aspect)? Shouldn't it be the same value for all interactions (134)?**

**2. Does this affect the t-statistic and p-values? I've read various threads suggesting dfs for mixed models is a little iffy.**

Note that I get the same pattern in the results when using a subsample (below) or the full dataset, which is over 24k rows.

Any input greatly appreciated!

```
ts.df <- dput(ts.df)
structure(list(rad = c(568.9946, 651.3894, 2357.642, 332.5853, 
1159.373, 526.5878, 741.4781, 255.0066, 637.1071, 645.6719, 202.0328, 
40.16373, 174.3512, 260.7356, 469.1678, 697.1382, 658.3321, 112.5003, 
2099.098, 1825.127, 1083.334, 190.0963, 473.1779, 140.5043, 1552.145, 
149.2376, 88.51754, 616.9649, 413.6272, 117.2539, 1068.122, 748.5656, 
365.4404, 652.9627, 834.4014, 313.6669, 404.823, 727.2624, 469.0989, 
737.2651, 1187.93, 41.71962, 584.9353, 286.3429, 19.10779, 137.424, 
3115.915, 189.5028, 57.47164, 122.4306, 263.965, 694.7066, 63.16661, 
677.0923, 375.3816, 77.76267, 217.5214, 134.8938, 402.754, 123.7094, 
429.8197, 1174.325, 723.5693, 136.6322, 429.8757, 193.9041, 849.5849, 
957.2107, 890.8044, 97.21737, 98.39217, 276.4654, 1040.834, 120.7995, 
323.9911, 460.2359, 558.5402, 477.4929, 304.0685, 155.2657, 109.8011, 
156.7398, 328.6714, 200.0480952, 1248.939, 678.0077, 620.4923, 
862.7459, 426.3893, 690.2304, 416.31, 1215.48, 886.1071, 87.05884, 
83.80122, 742.103, 502.108, 727.2046, 540.4885, 237.4726, 577.8321, 
826.9456, 149.558, 187.3401, 409.9789, 459.4851, 616.0131, 266.7044, 
225.6053, 289.7804, 249.082, 182.7243278, 176.0612, 37.67966, 
342.4724, 397.5421, 184.1033, 327.0741, 84.38014, 301.4254, 126.4002, 
733.8764008, 297.3074, 422.7084, 68.4743, 538.5738, 66.18022, 
845.9807, 167.8514, 792.5006, 402.5078, 1518.074, 1059.566, 1227.25, 
918.6581, 109.9804, 107.3047, 327.1179, 467.4323, 659.4091, 401.9921, 
690.2866, 910.0718, 52.19872, 717.571, 164.7861, 823.5326, 583.7323, 
265.2228, 220.0545, 256.7616, 242.6999, 255.138, 468.4619, 260.2451, 
175.4737, 37.66008, 449.3004, 970.2553, 364.2589, 297.2044, 514.3994, 
264.0438, 281.4674, 194.0195, 75.42424, 1586.661, 261.4314, 426.4181, 
1599.925, 313.5258, 371.3934, 566.6539, 464.1759, 128.4761, 562.722, 
146.3413, 433.3366, 503.6455, 630.0894, 346.5492, 327.5857, 166.6714, 
142.7759, 143.1537, 443.8882, 291.8869, 416.7935, 170.1698, 470.5118, 
392.5265, 359.9348, 30.88397, 92.9986, 667.1687, 241.7186, 228.7813, 
597.5328, 324.397, 49.4077, 276.8525, 154.3649, 65.50689, 657.0503, 
436.2313, 423.4499, 322.6293, 542.9137, 219.6759, 451.3688, 182.2962, 
439.259, 133.002, 366.0664, 167.9943, 123.6052, 1450.244, 794.2945, 
398.494, 482.3709, 84.29346, 122.7802, 424.3229, 92.38698, 1205.918, 
971.5946, 182.6578, 404.4067, 1372.905, 658.2696, 612.6023, 646.0278, 
1348.785, 286.5841, 1088.859, 925.049, 191.3526, 1331.666, 245.7933, 
79.16953, 213.8415, 1152.401, 397.4821, 548.5455, 207.4304, 296.9538
), ba.mm2 = c(38948.55, 39050.76, 67819.27, 37238.33, 27052.56, 
4693.71, 31317.36, 17887.95, 36801.14, 30386.52, 14974.47, 5732.06, 
15123.19, 4045.759, 45432.16, 66934.09, 56272.44, 13196.97, 77978.64, 
95929.99, 134942.1, 11176.67, 16601.03, 10389.78, 68224.22, 51762.6, 
5735.818, 21184.39, 12997.37, 6042.378, 72443.99, 30184.79, 13451.07, 
38381.16, 32795.46, 3748.825, 34834.92, 60068.04, 46675.18, 53479.97, 
48642.29, 7061.383, 23827.39, 31827.56, 8522.334, 11872.24, 111147.5, 
14503.66, 7120.787, 6259.503, 29999.08, 46108.65, 19250.92, 15781.05, 
9648.317, 10938.48, 22236.27, 2230.393, 22118.02, 25649.75, 18035.7, 
36290.17, 22253.72, 13279.36, 33965.75, 9418.152, 25146.95, 53387.38, 
36608.26, 13090.08, 16868.84, 30246.41, 54186.49, 10367.39, 29365.14, 
5205.807, 46389.95, 19319.84, 47613.43, 10628.17, 63534.58, 40810.95, 
14075.68, 6628.837, 41340.45, 17347.8, 45800.12, 50051.04, 18395.48, 
61272.11, 10733.31, 18846.8, 72684.63, 8186.029, 6804.016, 100533.8, 
27986.37, 20451.48, 51210.81, 19007.74, 35163.86, 46509.14, 10597.13, 
16721.37, 4203.754, 43231.24, 21233.44, 33519.05, 115063.7, 41215.85, 
27164.04, 1606.162, 7230.39, 64296.35, 13036.2, 10777.43, 4216.404, 
62359.7, 11395.85, 53470.95, 8302.869, 9173.442, 8676.176, 26135.17, 
11263.41, 35304.93, 66893.74, 60221.05, 7193.963, 57291.16, 10112.7, 
51038.48, 49165.96, 64303.54, 33460.01, 11395.47, 11182.67, 8945.024, 
9003.456, 42232.47, 29591.56, 17384.24, 14611.44, 7174.733, 17526.15, 
7404.751, 38888.41, 49792.04, 3670.236, 4468.905, 16598.29, 8180.899, 
11391.69, 22889.07, 29740.53, 14183.97, 7935.244, 43771.71, 35557.15, 
56949.72, 38897.5, 43714.63, 6399.953, 8907.513, 12574.5, 8690.05, 
29675.77, 36393.57, 42362.24, 98779.16, 12532, 6218.343, 33084.98, 
35203.09, 8884.109, 32983.82, 12742.41, 44471.65, 37785.53, 27655.26, 
44902.53, 21733.79, 41724.78, 8335.849, 7157.028, 99719.49, 114831.8, 
32222.14, 7557.441, 6907.627, 13075.49, 36751.51, 41282.8, 4669.455, 
27020.5, 11057.44, 11527.54, 53399.66, 23883.24, 14286.33, 4586.978, 
9713.191, 12468.19, 7620.748, 42699.99, 30822.48, 5085.531, 22990.01, 
12835.41, 108969.5, 9693.636, 39748.77, 9860.129, 6182.056, 8039.476, 
10191.64, 66960.69, 34809.13, 68928.8, 17962.46, 12584.83, 16896.02, 
49114.09, 9553.839, 76988.93, 127900.3, 15370.5, 61784.75, 17977.67, 
30709.94, 57947.21, 27846, 38871.63, 37143.31, 42032.37, 42388.51, 
29560.46, 126840.1, 8356.252, 10786.26, 4154.484, 53979.56, 8621.78, 
32176.34, 28317.67, 9926.417), dmg = c("moderate", "severe", 
"moderate", "very severe", "light", "moderate", "severe", "moderate", 
"moderate", "moderate", "very severe", "very severe", "moderate", 
"moderate", "moderate", "very severe", "severe", "severe", "moderate", 
"light", "severe", "very severe", "light", "moderate", "moderate", 
"severe", "very severe", "moderate", "severe", "very severe", 
"moderate", "severe", "moderate", "severe", "moderate", "moderate", 
"very severe", "severe", "severe", "moderate", "very severe", 
"very severe", "moderate", "moderate", "moderate", "moderate", 
"severe", "moderate", "very severe", "moderate", "moderate", 
"very severe", "moderate", "severe", "severe", "moderate", "moderate", 
"moderate", "moderate", "severe", "moderate", "severe", "moderate", 
"severe", "severe", "moderate", "light", "moderate", "moderate", 
"very severe", "moderate", "moderate", "severe", "moderate", 
"severe", "moderate", "severe", "severe", "moderate", "very severe", 
"severe", "severe", "moderate", "light", "moderate", "moderate", 
"moderate", "moderate", "severe", "severe", "very severe", "light", 
"severe", "moderate", "very severe", "severe", "severe", "severe", 
"severe", "severe", "severe", "severe", "very severe", "moderate", 
"moderate", "moderate", "very severe", "severe", "light", "very severe", 
"severe", "light", "moderate", "moderate", "moderate", "moderate", 
"moderate", "severe", "very severe", "moderate", "moderate", 
"light", "moderate", "very severe", "very severe", "moderate", 
"severe", "moderate", "very severe", "moderate", "moderate", 
"moderate", "moderate", "moderate", "moderate", "very severe", 
"moderate", "moderate", "very severe", "severe", "moderate", 
"severe", "severe", "very severe", "very severe", "very severe", 
"moderate", "very severe", "very severe", "moderate", "light", 
"moderate", "moderate", "moderate", "moderate", "light", "moderate", 
"severe", "very severe", "severe", "severe", "severe", "moderate", 
"moderate", "light", "moderate", "light", "very severe", "moderate", 
"severe", "moderate", "moderate", "moderate", "severe", "moderate", 
"moderate", "very severe", "severe", "moderate", "severe", "severe", 
"moderate", "very severe", "very severe", "moderate", "severe", 
"light", "moderate", "moderate", "moderate", "light", "moderate", 
"moderate", "light", "moderate", "light", "moderate", "severe", 
"severe", "severe", "moderate", "very severe", "light", "severe", 
"severe", "moderate", "moderate", "very severe", "moderate", 
"severe", "very severe", "very severe", "moderate", "moderate", 
"very severe", "moderate", "moderate", "severe", "severe", "severe", 
"moderate", "very severe", "moderate", "very severe", "severe", 
"severe", "moderate", "severe", "light", "moderate", "very severe", 
"severe", "severe", "severe", "severe", "severe", "severe", "severe", 
"very severe", "severe", "very severe", "severe", "moderate", 
"moderate", "severe", "severe"), s_mayT = c(1.259235, 0.6174769, 
0.5591352, -0.2576481, 0.5591352, -1.191115, -1.541165, 0.7341602, 
0.5007936, -0.3159897, 0.4424519, 0.3841102, 0.5591352, -0.02428141, 
-0.5493564, 0.3257686, 0.3841102, 0.2090852, 1.959335, 0.09240192, 
1.725968534, -0.8994064, 0.6174769, 0.5591352, -0.7243814, 0.7925019, 
-0.1409647, 0.6758186, -0.8410647, -1.599506, 1.317577, -0.7243814, 
0.3257686, 0.5007936, -0.3159897, -0.02428141, 0.5591352, -0.2576481, 
1.43426, 1.142552, -0.9577481, 0.03406025, 0.5007936, 0.5591352, 
0.6174769, 0.6174769, -1.307798044, -0.1993064, 1.725969, -0.5493564, 
-0.8410647, 0.5007936, 0.9675269, -0.2576481, 0.3257686, 1.317577, 
-0.1409647, -0.8410647, 1.259235, 0.9091852, -0.2576481, 0.7341602, 
-0.02428141, 0.5007936, -1.132773, 0.7925019, 0.7925019, 1.550944, 
-0.2576481, 0.9675269, 0.7341602, 0.9675269, 0.6758186, -0.1993064, 
0.5007936, 0.4424519, -0.3743314, 1.492602, -0.08262308, 0.4424519, 
0.7925019, 0.7925019, 0.5591352, 0.559135347, -0.3159897, -0.02428141, 
0.5591352, -0.7243814, -0.7243814, -0.2576481, -1.424481, 1.609285, 
-1.01609, 0.4424519, -0.7827231, 1.08421022, 1.317577, 0.3841102, 
-0.8410647, 0.2090852, -0.4326731, -1.01609, -1.424481, 0.5007936, 
-0.7243814, 0.09240192, 1.375919, 1.08421, 1.142552, 0.6174769, 
-0.1409647, -0.024281303, 0.4424519, 1.200894, -1.191115, 0.5007936, 
-0.02428141, -0.024281414, 1.142552, 1.550944, -0.3743314, 0.38411024, 
0.5591352, 0.2090852, 0.9675269, -0.02428141, 0.1507436, 1.142552, 
0.9091852, -0.7243814, 0.6174769, 1.317577, 0.1507436, 1.317577, 
1.550944, 0.1507436, 1.08421, 0.4424519, -1.599506, 1.43426, 
-0.02428141, 1.609285, -1.482823, 0.9091852, 0.2090852, 0.3257686, 
0.09240192, 0.5591352, -0.6660397, -0.5493564, 0.7925019, -1.191115, 
0.6758186, -0.6660397, 0.5591352, 0.9675269, 0.5591352, 1.492602, 
-0.6076981, 1.492602, -0.5493564, 0.6758186, 0.4424519, 1.259235, 
-0.8410647, 0.7341602, 1.025869, 1.842652, 0.5007936, 0.85084356, 
1.550944, 0.4424519, 0.1507436, 0.3257686, 1.900994, 1.842652, 
0.6758186, 0.03406025, 1.259235, -1.424481, 1.492602, -0.4910147, 
1.08421, 0.9091852, 0.5007936, -1.307798044, 0.9091852, 0.9675269, 
-1.191115, 0.4424519, 0.7341602, 1.842652, -0.6076981, 1.025869, 
0.5007936, 0.6174769, 0.5007936, 1.492602, -0.1409647, 0.6758186, 
0.6758186, -0.3743314, 0.3257686, 0.3257686, 1.08421, -0.6076981, 
-1.191115, 0.3841102, 1.375919, -0.7243814, -0.4910147, 0.6758186, 
-0.5493564, -0.4326731, -1.01609, 0.6174769, 1.317577, 0.7341602, 
0.7341602, 1.259235, 0.6174769, 0.1507436, 0.5591352, -0.6660397, 
-0.3743314, -0.724381394, 0.1507436, 0.442451905, -0.7827231, 
0.7341602, 0.7341602, -0.5493564, 0.6758186, 0.6758186, -1.657848, 
0.6758186, 0.8508436, -0.374331404, -0.8410647, -2.06624, -0.6660397, 
0.6758186, -0.02428141, 0.1507436, 1.375919, 0.6174769), aspect = c(0.07503349, 
-0.5574336, -0.9933805, 1.728357, 0.6068549, 0.07503349, 1.871793, 
-0.5782978, -0.9933805, -0.9933805, -1.056711, 0.2583826, -0.2813211, 
0.07503349, 0.6068549, -1.065121, -0.94716, -0.9243012, -0.9933805, 
-1.052893, 0.606854874, 2.225803, -0.2057146, -0.2813211, -0.9933805, 
-0.323097, -0.5782978, 0.07503349, -0.8995769, -0.5782978, -0.9933805, 
-0.94716, -0.5782978, -0.5574336, -0.9933805, 0.07503349, -1.065121, 
-0.323097, -0.323097, -0.9933805, 1.728357, 0.2583826, -0.470495, 
-0.9933805, -0.829808, -0.829808, 0.606854874, -0.6695282, 0.2583826, 
0.07503349, -0.829808, 1.728357, -0.829808, -0.94716, -0.8995769, 
-0.5782978, -1.052893, 0.07503349, 0.07503349, -0.94716, -0.5782978, 
-0.9243012, -0.829808, 0.918043, -0.5782978, -0.5782978, 0.6068549, 
-0.9933805, -0.9933805, 0.2583826, -0.2813211, -0.829808, -0.323097, 
-0.5782978, -0.94716, 0.07503349, -0.9243012, -0.8995769, 0.6068549, 
0.2583826, -0.323097, -0.323097, -0.470495, 0.54836126, -0.9933805, 
0.07503349, -0.9933805, -0.9933805, -0.94716, -0.323097, 0.2583826, 
0.6068549, -0.323097, 0.07503349, -0.5782978, 0.606854874, -0.323097, 
-0.94716, -0.94716, -0.9243012, -0.94716, -0.323097, 0.2583826, 
-0.470495, 0.07503349, -0.9933805, 2.225803, -0.5782978, -1.052893, 
-1.065121, -0.5574336, 0.54836126, 0.07503349, -0.9933805, 0.07503349, 
-0.829808, 0.07503349, 0.606854874, -0.5782978, -0.9933805, -1.052893, 
0.54836126, -0.470495, 1.728357, 0.2583826, 0.07503349, -0.323097, 
-0.9933805, 0.2583826, -0.9933805, -0.470495, -0.9933805, -0.9933805, 
-0.9933805, -0.9933805, -0.5782978, -0.2813211, 0.07503349, -1.056711, 
-0.323097, 0.07503349, -0.8995769, -0.8995769, 0.2583826, 2.225803, 
-0.5782978, -0.9933805, -1.065121, -1.056711, 0.07503349, -0.2057146, 
-0.829808, 0.07503349, -0.470495, 0.6068549, -0.2057146, -0.2813211, 
-0.323097, 1.728357, -0.323097, -0.323097, -0.5782978, 0.07503349, 
0.07503349, -0.2057146, -0.2813211, 0.6068549, -1.065121, 0.6068549, 
0.606854874, -0.5782978, 0.07503349, 0.07503349, -0.9243012, 
-0.2813211, -0.9933805, 2.225803, -0.5782978, 0.07503349, -0.94716, 
-0.323097, -1.052893, -1.065121, 0.2583826, -0.2813211, 0.606854874, 
-1.052893, -0.829808, 0.07503349, 0.07503349, -0.2057146, -0.2813211, 
0.6068549, 0.6068549, -0.9933805, -0.2057146, -0.2813211, -0.323097, 
-0.5574336, -0.9243012, 0.07503349, 0.2583826, -0.2057146, -0.8995769, 
-0.5782978, -0.9933805, 0.07503349, 2.225803, -0.6695282, 0.6068549, 
-0.5782978, 1.728357, -0.470495, 0.07503349, -1.056711, -0.470495, 
-0.9933805, -0.5574336, -0.323097, -0.9243012, -1.052893, -1.056711, 
-0.9933805, 0.2583826, 0.6068549, 0.606854874, 0.07503349, 0.606854874, 
0.6068549, 2.004497, -1.065121, 1.871793, -0.323097, -0.5782978, 
-0.323097, -0.323097, -0.94716, 0.606854874, 0.2583826, 0.918043, 
-1.056711, -0.323097, 0.07503349, -0.829808, 1.871793, -0.8995769
), year = c(1995L, 1997L, 1987L, 1989L, 1996L, 1985L, 1992L, 
1994L, 1983L, 1984L, 1997L, 1983L, 1987L, 1987L, 1997L, 1989L, 
1996L, 1987L, 1995L, 1984L, 1990L, 2000L, 1997L, 1987L, 2000L, 
1988L, 1989L, 1988L, 2000L, 1992L, 1991L, 1985L, 1996L, 1996L, 
1984L, 1983L, 1983L, 1999L, 1990L, 1994L, 2000L, 1989L, 1996L, 
1987L, 1988L, 1998L, 1992L, 1999L, 1990L, 1989L, 1986L, 1997L, 
1993L, 1984L, 1987L, 1993L, 1998L, 1984L, 1990L, 1988L, 1989L, 
1988L, 1996L, 1993L, 1992L, 1991L, 1998L, 1993L, 1986L, 1998L, 
1997L, 1993L, 1991L, 1999L, 1997L, 1994L, 1999L, 1993L, 1998L, 
1987L, 1988L, 1988L, 1983L, 1997L, 1984L, 1983L, 1987L, 2000L, 
1985L, 1999L, 1992L, 1990L, 2000L, 1998L, 1985L, 1988L, 1993L, 
1996L, 2000L, 1996L, 1986L, 1985L, 1992L, 1996L, 1986L, 1989L, 
1993L, 1991L, 1998L, 1996L, 1989L, 1989L, 1998L, 1988L, 1985L, 
1994L, 1987L, 1989L, 1998L, 1993L, 1983L, 1987L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1998L, 1987L, 1987L, 1994L, 1994L, 2000L, 1987L, 1991L, 1999L, 
1998L, 1993L, 1983L, 1994L, 1998L, 1992L, 1990L, 1987L, 1990L, 
1992L, 1991L, 1983L, 1987L, 1989L, 1983L, 1984L, 1989L, 1998L, 
1985L, 1988L, 2000L, 1995L, 1988L, 1987L, 1995L, 1984L, 1995L, 
1986L, 1996L, 1994L, 1995L, 2000L, 1997L, 1988L, 1995L, 1990L, 
1991L, 1995L, 1994L, 1996L, 1997L, 1995L, 1990L, 1994L, 1984L, 
1990L, 1992L, 1995L, 1996L, 1998L, 1994L, 1983L, 1992L, 1997L, 
1993L, 2000L, 1994L, 1991L, 1990L, 1987L, 1988L, 1983L, 1997L, 
1996L, 1995L, 1989L, 1998L, 1988L, 1986L, 1987L, 1983L, 1994L, 
1985L, 1985L, 1996L, 1993L, 1985L, 1986L, 1994L, 1985L, 1999L, 
1985L, 1987L, 1991L, 1991L, 1998L, 1993L, 1995L, 1983L, 1987L, 
1985L, 1984L, 2000L, 1996L, 1987L, 1985L, 1983L, 1997L, 1984L, 
1991L, 1996L, 1992L, 1994L, 1998L, 1984L, 2000L, 1992L, 1984L, 
1991L, 1983L, 1997L, 1993L, 1997L), plot = c("BD3.5", "N130", 
"CPCPRW", "N124", "N307", "BD3.5", "M129", "M002", "CPCPRW", 
"CPCPRW", "N117", "T105", "F109", "BD3.5", "S157", "D022", "D017", 
"D012", "CPCPRW", "H039", "BCEF", "N142", "N424", "F109", "CPCPRW", 
"MDMX", "L135", "BD3.5", "M317", "L135", "CPCPRW", "D017", "M002", 
"N130", "CPCPRW", "BD3.5", "D022", "MDMX", "MDMX", "CPCPRW", 
"N124", "T105", "C138", "CPCPRW", "F107", "F107", "BCEF", "F028", 
"T105", "BD3.5", "F107", "N124", "F107", "D017", "M317", "M002", 
"D953", "BD3.5", "BD3.5", "D017", "M002", "D012", "F107", "TCC55_57", 
"S244", "M002", "N307", "CPCPRW", "CPCPRW", "T105", "F109", "F107", 
"MDMX", "M002", "D017", "BD3.5", "D012", "M317", "S157", "T105", 
"MDMX", "MDMX", "C138", "A218", "CPCPRW", "BD3.5", "CPCPRW", 
"CPCPRW", "D017", "MDMX", "T105", "N307", "MDMX", "BD3.5", "L135", 
"BCEF", "MDMX", "D017", "D017", "D012", "D017", "MDMX", "T105", 
"C138", "BD3.5", "CPCPRW", "N142", "S244", "H039", "D022", "N130", 
"A218", "BD3.5", "CPCPRW", "BD3.5", "F107", "BD3.5", "BCEF", 
"L135", "CPCPRW", "D953", "A218", "C138", "N124", "T105", "BD3.5", 
"MDMX", "CPCPRW", "T105", "CPCPRW", "C138", "CPCPRW", "CPCPRW", 
"CPCPRW", "CPCPRW", "L135", "F109", "BD3.5", "N117", "MDMX", 
"BD3.5", "M317", "M317", "T105", "N142", "L135", "CPCPRW", "D022", 
"N117", "BD3.5", "N424", "F107", "BD3.5", "C138", "S157", "N424", 
"F109", "MDMX", "N124", "MDMX", "MDMX", "S244", "BD3.5", "BD3.5", 
"N424", "F109", "N307", "D022", "S157", "BCEF", "M002", "BD3.5", 
"BD3.5", "D012", "F109", "CPCPRW", "N142", "S244", "BD3.5", "D017", 
"MDMX", "D953", "D022", "T105", "F109", "BCEF", "H039", "F107", 
"BD3.5", "BD3.5", "N424", "F109", "S157", "N307", "CPCPRW", "N424", 
"F109", "MDMX", "N130", "D012", "BD3.5", "T105", "N424", "M317", 
"S244", "CPCPRW", "BD3.5", "N142", "F028", "BCEF", "L135", "N124", 
"C138", "BD3.5", "N117", "C138", "CPCPRW", "N130", "MDMX", "D012", 
"D953", "N117", "CPCPRW", "T105", "BCEF", "BCEF", "BD3.5", "BCEF", 
"N307", "LVN137", "D022", "M129", "MDMX", "S244", "MDMX", "MDMX", 
"D017", "BCEF", "T105", "TCC55_57", "N117", "MDMX", "BD3.5", 
"F107", "M129", "M317"), id = c("BD3.5P03", "N130t08", "CPCRPt14", 
"N124t09", "N307t15", "BD3.5P14", "M129t04", "M002t13", "CPCRPt20", 
"CPCRPt12", "N117t05", "T105t07", "F109t50", "BD3.5P19", "S157t25", 
"D022t19", "D017t09", "D012t35", "CPCRPt14", "H039t16", "BCEFPt07", 
"N142t21", "N424t15", "F109t52", "CPCRPt05", "MDMXPt21", "L135t25", 
"BD3.5P07", "M317t16", "L135t25", "CPCRPt07", "D017t03", "M002t09", 
"N130t08", "CPCRPt01", "BD3.5P14", "D022t04", "MDMXPt21", "MDMXPt07", 
"CPCRPt10", "N124t10", "T105t21", "C138t06", "CPCRPt12", "F107t40", 
"F107t40", "BCEFPt06", "F028Pt24", "T105t21", "BD3.5P18", "F107t25", 
"N124t10", "F107t30", "D017t22", "M317t43", "M002t06", "D953t33", 
"BD3.5P17", "BD3.5P07", "D017t26", "M002t27", "D012t30", "F107t05", 
"tcc55", "S244t08", "M002t30", "N307t14", "CPCRPt23", "CPCRPt04", 
"T105t03", "F109t50", "F107t16", "MDMXPt21", "M002t30", "D017t04", 
"BD3.5P17", "D012t30", "M317t08", "S157t91", "T105t03", "MDMXPt10", 
"MDMXPt18", "C138t36", "A218t30", "CPCRPt21", "BD3.5P07", "CPCRPt08", 
"CPCRPt03", "D017t24", "MDMXPt20", "T105t02", "N307t15", "MDMXPt01", 
"BD3.5P18", "L135t21", "BCEFPt06", "MDMXPt13", "D017t22", "D017t10", 
"D012t07", "D017t31", "MDMXPt24", "T105t04", "C138t36", "BD3.5P24", 
"CPCRPt21", "N142t02", "S244t08", "H039t01", "D022t04", "N130t33", 
"A218t25", "BD3.5P10", "CPCRPt19", "BD3.5P12", "F107t40", "BD3.5P10", 
"BCEFPt13", "L135t56", "CPCRPt25", "D953t12", "A218t29", "C138t13", 
"N124t01", "T105t04", "BD3.5P05", "MDMXPt11", "CPCRPt11", "T105t07", 
"CPCRPt08", "C138t13", "CPCRPt05", "CPCRPt03", "CPCRPt11", "CPCRPt16", 
"L135t17", "F109t52", "BD3.5P20", "N117t25", "MDMXPt18", "BD3.5P06", 
"M317t08", "M317t06", "T105t21", "N142t02", "L135t36", "CPCRPt22", 
"D022t57", "N117104", "BD3.5P19", "N424t10", "F107t40", "BD3.5P11", 
"C138t22", "S157t17", "N424t10", "F109t24", "MDMXPt19", "N124t09", 
"MDMXPt21", "MDMXPt16", "S244t03", "BD3.5P13", "BD3.5P14", "N424t50", 
"F109t39", "N307t24", "D022t91", "S157t25", "BCEFPt02", "M002t31", 
"BD3.5P23", "BD3.5P06", "D012t17", "F109t24", "CPCRPt12", "N142t23", 
"S244t10", "BD3.5P04", "D017t01", "MDMXPt17", "D953t33", "D022t04", 
"T105t17", "F109t41", "BCEFPt09", "H039t01", "F107t25", "BD3.5P23", 
"BD3.5P21", "N424t54", "F109t07", "S157t25", "N307t26", "CPCRPt09", 
"N424t14", "F109t52", "MDMXPt23", "N130t21", "D012t35", "BD3.5P23", 
"T105t30", "N424t25", "M317t43", "S244t03", "CPCRPt12", "BD3.5P18", 
"N142t02", "F028Pt24", "BCEFPt17", "L135t01", "N124t09", "C138t04", 
"BD3.5P08", "N117t26", "C138t04", "CPCRPt19", "N130t08", "MDMXPt12", 
"D012t07", "D953t24", "N117t22", "CPCRPt10", "T105t30", "BCEFPt22", 
"BCEFPt10", "BD3.5P12", "BCEFPt13", "N307t10", "L13712", "D022t57", 
"M129t04", "MDMXPt14", "S244t04", "MDMXPt19", "MDMXPt15", "D017t04", 
"BCEFPt07", "T105t07", "tcc56", "N117t46", "MDMXPt05", "BD3.5P11", 
"F107t16", "M129t22", "M317t57")), row.names = c(NA, -246L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: see the quotation from Pinheiro and Bates at https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#why-doesnt-lme4-display-denominator-degrees-of-freedomp-values-what-other-options-do-i-have

Comment: I've voted to close this as belonging on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). If you like, you can repost there (and delete this version) yourself ...